# Create user in Readers Account Snowflake

Tags: permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-accounts

I have created a `share` and added that share to a `reader account`.

Now I have executed a `create user` statement there in the reader account i.e.

```
 CREATE or replace USER client_test
 PASSWORD             = 'Client4321'
 LOGIN_NAME           = 'client'
 DISPLAY_NAME         = 'client test'
 FIRST_NAME           = 'client'
 LAST_NAME            = 'test'
 EMAIL                = 'mukul.kumar@gmail.com'
 DEFAULT_ROLE         = sysadmin;
```

This statement gets executed without any error and also I can see the user details under the account tab in snowflake UI

but still, when I am trying to login into this newly created user, there is an `error of incorrect username or password` coming up.

Is creating a user in a reader account not allowed or anything like there in snowflake?

I haven't found documentation on this as such. It will be appreciated if anyone helps me out with this.

Comment: No, you can create users in Reader account just like any other account. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-config.html#task-3-create-users

Comment: Yes, @SrinathMenon. Also, I am seeing the user details under the account tab. But on login its saying `Incorrect username or password was specified.`

Comment: Are you passing the user as client or client_test?

Comment: `client_test` actually

Comment: Have you tried to login with "client" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the login_name is the one which should be used for logging in to the SF application. Use "client" and "Client4321" to login and it will be successful.